# Shared Prefrences to save a authentication token in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have never used `sharedprefrences` before, now what i want to store a authentication token in `sharedprefrences`. This is my code where i am getting user token in `hawkerauthToken` which is a string, i want to store this token in `sharedprefrences`

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL, object,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            VolleyLog.v("v_response", response.toString(4));
                            Log.d("resopnse", response.toString());

                            hawkerauthToken = String.valueOf(response.get("token"));
                            Log.d("tokeennnn" , hawkerauthToken);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: duplicate of this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example).

Answer (score 6):

**SharedPreferences**

**Save:**

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
 preferences.edit().putString("token", hawkerauthToken).commit();
```

**retrieve:**

```
   String token = preferences.getString("token","");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(inboxFragment.context);
        sp.edit().putString("keyname", "keyValue").apply();
```